# Refresh token not triggered Plugin.FirebasePushNotification - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I am trying to send remote notifications in my mobile app built using Xamarin.Forms. I have made all the necessary console settings in Firebase and uploaded google-services.json and GoogleService-info.plist. The notification function works perfectly fine with Xamarin.Forms android but the same code does not work for Xamarin forms iOS.

My App.xamal.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
     public App()
     {
            InitializeComponent();
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) => {
                  string token = p.Token;
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN REFRESHED: {token}");
                  _ = MyService.UpdateUserDeviceToken(token);
            };
     }
     ...
}
```

And this is how my AppDelegate is stored:

```
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }

        public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            LocalNotificationCenter.ResetApplicationIconBadgeNumber(uiApplication);
            base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
        }
    }
}
```

Along with this, I have also enabled Push notifications in Entitlements.plist and also in Info.plist enabled Remote Notification in Background Modes and also added
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled

But still, it does not trigger on refresh token event. This thing works perfectly fine with android and the refresh token is triggered. I have taken reference to this nugget package [Plugin.PushNotification](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.PushNotification#readme-body-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error with my settings. While giving provisioning, I gave it manual provisioning but did not manually point out the Custom Entitlements. So it got fixed by selecting the Custom Entitlement in the manual provisioning section or selecting automatic provisioning to sign in and do all the required settings automatically.